# Incompatibility of numpy.sum() with Python 3

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, python-3.x

In Python 2.7 one could write:

```
sum(map(int, "123"))
```

In Python 3 it became:

```
sum(x for x in map(int, "123"))
```

Is there a way to make it more concise?

EDIT:

I was running pylab, which imports `sum()` from `numpy` changing semantics of the first snippet. IDLE produces the same results for both Python 2.7 and Python 3.3 as DSM noticed.

NOTE:

I would appreciate anyone down voting this question to leave a comment with a short explanation. I edited the title (originally: *Is there a way to get back a concise notation for map() in Python 3?*) to reflect my better understanding of underlying issue. What else bothers you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` still exists in Python 3; in fact, your first code snippet should still work.

Comment: It doesn't produce the same result in Python 3: it produces `<builtins.map at 0x5f08438>` instead of int.

Comment: @PaulJurczak: Maybe `map` does, but the result of `sum` is exactly the same as in Python 2.

Comment: The snippet `sum(map(int, "123"))` when run with CPython 3.3.1 on my system produces `<builtins.map at 0x60c15c0>`. Have you tried to actually run it?

Comment: @PaulJurczak: Yes. Running `sum(map(int, "123"))` on CPython 3.3.0+ `7531dba22872` yields `6` for me.

Comment: @PaulJurczak: that should definitely work.  Did you happen to do a `*` import from `numpy`, so that you're using `numpy`'s `sum` instead?.. [update] Okay, I've just confirmed that if you're using `numpy.sum`, that's what'll happen.  Either you did it yourself or you're using an environment (pylab, e.g.) which did it for you.

Comment: @DSM You are right, it works in IDLE, but not in pylab, which I was using. Another lesson learned, Python week 2. Thank you.

Comment: Beware: `pylab` shadows several of the builtins, not only `sum`, but `any` and `all`, with the `numpy` versions which don't play nicely with generators.  Try `if all(False for i in range(3)): print('epic fail!')` in both, for example.  IPython in non-pylab mode is my preferred environment.

Answer (score 0):

The more Python3-ish way of doing it would be

```
sum(int(d) for d in "123")
```

though as was pointed out, map() still exists.

Comment: And that's how I initially wrote it. I've seen other people using `sum(map(int, "123"))`, but it doesn't work in Python 3 any longer, so I was curious about the new pattern using `map()`. BTW, the question is not about `map()` existence, but about its new semantics.

Comment: `map()` returns an iterator in Python3, where it used to return a list. sum() takes an iterator, so that's still OK, but if you actually want the list like you had before, you need to ask for it explicitly with `list(map(...))`.

Answer (score -2):

Oooops, I found an answer in related questions links:

```
sum(list(map(int, "123")))
```

Comment: There's no need for the intermediate `list`; `sum` works on generators.

Comment: It doesn't when you are using pylab in default configuration. See comments above.